# How does one enable different backgrounds for each viewport screen in linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, wallpaper

I was wondering if it was possible to enable different desktop backgrounds in the four different gnome viewport screens using linux mint?

Answer (score 2):

No. This is a open bug for more than 10 years now and for some reason, it looks like there is no volunteer to take a stab at fixing it ...

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48004